# Bounded treewidth implies bounded clique-width

Tags: graphs, treewidth

We have a graph G of treewidth $\operatorname{tw}(G)\leq k$, for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. I've seen a claim that that implies that the clique-width of the same graph is at most $k \cdot 2^k$. This implies that given a tree decomposition of the graph we can construct a proper expression tree using at most $k \cdot 2^k$ labels.

I'm guessing that the $k$ in the decomposition allows us to "construct" a node of the tree decomposition, i.e. regardless how the vertices in one bag are connected, we can easily connect them since we have $k+1$-ish labels at our disposal. However, I don't quite see how we can use that fact to construct the complete expression tree (and therefore the $k\cdot 2^k$-expression).

How can we construct the proper expression and therefore prove that graphs of bounded treewidth are a subclass of graphs of bounded clique-width

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes the construction more complicated, but it seems that the $k$ factor is not necessary: the paper "D.G. Corneil, U. Rotics; On the relationship between clique-width and treewidth SIAM J. Comput. 34 825-847 (2005)" claims a bound of $3\cdot 2^{k-1}$. The paper or its references may help.

Comment: The proof here might be simpler: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04479.pdf.